# How to add plugin item to IntelliJ IDEA context menu?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I have written a plugin for **IntelliJ IDEA** . It works when I press **alt + insert** .

[image: works with alt + insert]

But I want it to create icon in this menu ,so that I can run my plugin from here.

[image: I want to add somewhere here]

How can I config it?

Answer (score 0):

In the <actions> section of your plugin.xml, you need to register your action to that context menu (which happens to be called "ProjectViewPopupMenu")

```
    <action id="com.example.someaction" class="com.example.someaction" text="Do Something"
            description="Does Something">
        <add-to-group group-id="ProjectViewPopupMenu" anchor="last"/>
    </action>
```

Also, when editing your action class, there is a helper action when your cursor is on an AnAction class name that isn't registered, which gives you a very nice UI to help you register your action and fill in the plugin.xml details for you, which includes a full listing of action groups to help you find the specific group you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you correctly, please try the following:
open Preferences >> Keymap >> Plug-ins >> select your plug-in >> double click on plug-in's item >> Add Mouse shortcut >> save your right click option.